Trivial free-homotopy class then triviale path-homotopy class in manifold
I'm stuck with the exercise 6.27 of 'Introduction to Riemannian manifold' of M. Lee.
In particular the exercise is the following:

Let $M$ be a differentiable connected manifold, let $x\in M$, let $\sigma$ a (continuous) loop based on $x$, then:
$\sigma$ is freely homotopic to the constant path iff $\sigma$ is path homotopic to the constant path

The direction $\leftarrow$ is tautological, but the $\rightarrow$ direction i don't understad what particulary topological properties of beeing a connected manifold i have to use.
